# How can I dynamically update ttk.combobox?

Tags: python-3.x, combobox, tkinter

I am creating a GUI using Python 3.4 and Tkinter on a Windows 8 computer.

The GUI has some Entry inputs at the top, then some comboboxes. I want the combobox to acquire a list of options from a text file that is described by the previous inputs (file name, the row in which the requisite information is found, delimiter type, etc.). I am trying to use the postcommand, but it seems to run first thing and never update, rather then update every time I access the drop down menu of the combobox.

```
    datatypes = []
    datatypes = ttk.Combobox(tab_loc, textvariable=std1, values=datatypes, postcommand=self.get_datatypes(datatypes,
           self.flnm2.get(), self.hl2_text.get(), self.delim2.get(), self.fcd2_text.get())).grid(pady=v_pad,
           padx=h_pad, row=8, column=1, sticky=EW)

    def get_datatypes(self, lst, flnm, hl, delim, fcd):
        # Problem: postcommand runs at start of GUI. Prevents updating.
        lst += ["test", "worked?"]
        print("stuff")
        lst += flnm
        lst += hl
        try:
            # open the file, get the line, break it apart.
        except:
            pass
```

`self.flnm2`, `self.hl2_text`, `self.delim2`, and `self.fcd2_text` are some of the previous inputs. They are StringVar.

When I run this code, the combobox has the options test, worked?, and two blank lines (presumably for `flnm` and `hl`). I plan to have multiple comboboxes like this, just with different inputs, so I need a function I can give inputs to and then  updates `datatypes`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `self.get_datatypes(...)` and assigning the result to the `postcommand` attribute at the time you create the combobox. That is why it runs exactly once: you told it to. Just like with `command` attributes, you must give a reference to a function when definining the `postcommand` attribute.

Create a method specifically for the post command for each combobox, use a reference to that for your `postcommand`, and then call `get_datatypes` from that function after fetching the values from the other widgets.

It should look something like this:

```
datatypes = ttk.Combobox(..., postcommand=self.combo_post_command, ...)
...
def combo_post_command(self):
    flnm2 = self.flnm2.get()
    hl2_text = self.hl2_text.get()
    delim2 = self.delim2.get()
    fcd2_text = self.fcd2_text.get()
    return self.get_datatypes(datatypes, flnm2, hl2_text, delim2, fcd2_text)
```

I'm not exactly sure what `datatypes` is supposed to be. You define it as an empty list, then reset it to be the widget itself. Regardless, this shows the general concept.

It may seem like you have a lot of duplicated code by having a function for each combobox, but you have to call all the `get()` functions somewhere. You either try to cram that all into the configuration of the widget, or you put it in a function. Putting it in the function is more explicit, and easier to debug and maintain over time.

Answer (score 6):

You can finish your homework with a simple `lambda` function.

```
valuetypes = ["bla1", "bla2", "bla3"]
datatypes = ttk.Combobox(..., values=valuetypes, 
                          postcommand=lambda: datatypes.configure(values=valuetypes), ...) 

valuetypes.append["another bla"]
```

When you click on the down-arrow of the `Combobox`, the changes will appear in the drop-down menu.