# populating one combobox based on another combo box using tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
v1=[]
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
frame1=Frame(root,bg='#80c1ff',bd=5)
frame1.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.1,relwidth=0.75,relheight=0.1,anchor='n')
lower_frame=Frame(root,bg='#80c1ff',bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.25,relwidth=0.75,relheight=0.6,anchor='n')
v=[]
def maincombo():
    Types=["MA","MM","MI","SYS","IN"]
    combo1=Combobox(frame1,values=Types)
    combo1.place(relx=0.05,rely=0.25)
    combo2=Combobox(frame1,values=v)
    combo2.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combofill)
    combo2.place(relx=0.45,rely=0.25)    
def combofill():
    if combo1.get()=="MA":
        v=[1,2,3,45]
        combo2=Combobox(frame1,values=v)
        combo2.place(relx=0.45,rely=0.25)
    if combo1.get()=="MM":
        v=[5,6,7,8,9]
        combo2=Combobox(frame1,values=v)
        combo2.place(relx=0.45,rely=0.25)    



maincombo()
root.mainloop()
```

I want to populate the one combobox based on selection of other combobox I,e types.But failed to do so with simple functions.

Comment: Take a look at [dynamic population of a ttk comobox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53978601) (I believe this is what you are after, though please do correct me if not)

Comment: Could you please code a bit based on mine,please?

Comment: I actually have seen a question like this on his community before, maybe take a look for it here?

Comment: but wont you have to pass an `event` parameter on to `combofill()` or something?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you code, most of what you need is already there. The changes I have made are as follows:

- Bound to `combo1` rather than `combo2` (as `combo1` is the one you want to monitor)
- Set `combo1` and `combo2` as global variables (so they can be used in the `combofill` method)
- Set the `combofill` method to accept the `event` arg (it would raise a `TypeError` otherwise)
- Use the `.config` method on `combo2` rather than creating a new one each time
- Set `combo2` to be empty when neither "MA" or "MM" are selected

Here is my implementation of that:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
v1=[]
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
frame1=Frame(root,bg='#80c1ff',bd=5)
frame1.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.1,relwidth=0.75,relheight=0.1,anchor='n')
lower_frame=Frame(root,bg='#80c1ff',bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.25,relwidth=0.75,relheight=0.6,anchor='n')
v=[]
def maincombo():
    global combo1, combo2
    Types=["MA","MM","MI","SYS","IN"]
    combo1=Combobox(frame1,values=Types)
    combo1.place(relx=0.05,rely=0.25)
    combo1.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combofill)
    combo2=Combobox(frame1,values=v)
    combo2.place(relx=0.45,rely=0.25)
def combofill(event):
    if combo1.get()=="MA":
        v=[1,2,3,45]
    elif combo1.get()=="MM":
        v=[5,6,7,8,9]
    else:
        v=[]
    combo2.config(values=v)

maincombo()
root.mainloop()
```

A couple other ideas for potential future consideration:

- I would recommend using the `grid` manager rather than the `place` manager as it will stop widgets overlapping, etc. (on my system, `combo2` slightly covers `combo1`)
- Use a dictionary rather than `if ... v=... elif ... v= ...` and then use the `get` method so you can give the `default` argument. For example:

  ```
  v={"MA": [1,2,3,45], 
     "MM": [5,6,7,8,9]}. \
     get(combo1.get(), [])
  ```

**EDIT:**

Responding to the question in the comments, the following is my implementation of how to make a "toggle combobox" using comma-separated values as requested.

As the combobox has already overwritten the value of the text area when our `<<ComboboxSelected>>` binding is called, I had to add a text variable trace so we could keep track of the previous value of the text area (and therefore append the new value, etc.). I am pretty sure that explanation is completely inadequate so: if in doubt, look at the code!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

root = Tk()

def log_last():
    global last, cur
    last = cur
    cur = tx.get()

def append_tx(event):
    if last:
        v = last.split(",")
    else:
        v = []
    v = list(filter(None, v))
    if cur in v:
        v.remove(cur)
    else:
        v.append(cur)
    tx.set(",".join(v))
    combo.selection_clear()
    combo.icursor("end")

last, cur = "", ""
tx = StringVar()
combo = Combobox(root, textvariable=tx, values=list(range(10)))
combo.pack()
combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", append_tx)
tx.trace("w", lambda a, b, c: log_last())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you Sir...I will try to implement.

Comment: Hi Jim,Is it possible to append to the existing selection with a comma.For example if in the combo2 if I have already selected 3 and later I selected 5 it should show 3,5 rather 3 overrode by 5.I added the below 2 lines to combofill"expression=expression+","+combo2.get()
    combo2.config(expression)

Comment: @pbeginner, please see my edited answer. I was concerned once you added a value, you would have to manually remove it from the text area and so made the code so selecting it a second time removes it from the list. If you want the options in the text area to be sorted, add `v.sort()` before the `tx.set...` line in `append_tx`. I am more than happy to help, but in the future please post this as a separate question (you can always @ me in a comment to bring it to my attention). NOTE: I have not tested this with the answer to the original question so am not sure if it will work in that context.

Comment: .,I just implemented like below with the original code. added two lines combo2.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', select)and wrote one function def select(event):
    global expression
    if combo2.get() in expression:
        messagebox.showerror("Error","IPR number already selected")
    else:
        expression=expression+","+combo2.get()
     
    combo2.set(expression[1:])